# In how many different ways can you order in line the letters of the word MONADOLOGY?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many different ways can you order in line the letters of the word MONADOLOGY?
I was thinking - because of the 3 O's, each permutation repeats $3!$ times. Because of that the answer should be $10!$ (all the ways to order the letters) divide by $3!$
What do you think?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reworded, you are asking how many strings can be constructed using letters from the multiset $\{A,D,G,L,M,N,O,O,O,Y\}$ where each letter is used exactly as many times as it appears in the multiset.

For notation, we often write each element only once, but will write a number to the left of each representing the number of times it appears in the multiset.  For your case, it is $\{1\cdot A, 1\cdot D, 1\cdot G, 1\cdot L, 1\cdot M, 1\cdot N, 3\cdot O, 1\cdot Y\}$

In general, with multiset $\mathcal{M} = \{\alpha_1\cdot A_1, \alpha_2\cdot A_2,\dots, \alpha_n\cdot A_n\}$ where $|\mathcal{M}|=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\dots+\alpha_n = N$,

the number of multipermutations will be $\frac{N!}{\alpha_1!\alpha_2!\dots\alpha_n!}$

This is such a commonly occurring problem that we give it its own notation:

$\binom{N}{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n}$

For your specific case, you have ten letters total, seven of which occurring once and one of which repeated a total of three times, so the total will be:

$\binom{10}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3}=\frac{10!}{1!1!1!1!1!1!1!3!}=\frac{10!}{3!}$

---

For additional example, the quintessential example is "How many arrangements of the letters of the word MISSISSIPPI exist?"

The multiset being $\{4\cdot I, 1\cdot M, 2\cdot P, 4\cdot S\}$

The number of multipermutations being $\binom{11}{4,1,2,4} = \frac{11!}{4!1!2!4!}$

---

The proof of the formula follows from induction and direct application of multiplication principle following the steps:

- Pick which of the $N$ locations are occupied by the $\alpha_1$ copies of $A_1$
- Pick which of the remaining $N-\alpha_1$ locations are occupied by the $\alpha_2$ copies of $A_2$
- Pick which of the remaining $N-\alpha_1-\alpha_2$ locations are occupied by the $\alpha_3$ copies of $A_3$
- $\dots$